# SVN: Can I copy a subset of files to a new tag?

Tags: svn, version-control, copy, tags, tagging

In my repo trunk I have a directory `unit-tests` that I want to keep out of my release tags. What I've been doing is copying trunk to a new tag, then deleting `unit-tests`. **Is this *OK*?** It feels wrong because it takes two revisions to tag every release. **Is there a way to *exclude* a directory from the svn copy?**

E.g. I have:

```
/trunk/unit-tests
/trunk/dir1
/trunk/file1
/trunk/file2
```

And I want to create:

```
/tags/release_123/dir1
/tags/release_123/file1
/tags/release_123/file2
```

I generally use Tortoise/Eclipse clients, but I could cli it if need be.

Comment: The unit tests go together with the code. I can't think of any reason *why* you would want snapshot the code but not the unit tests.

Comment: Sorry, "unit-test" was just as an example. Really there are several utilities developers might want access to, but that don't belong in "official" releases. My theory was the release tags should be identical to the .zip releases.

Comment: You could have some kind of build script/recipe file that creates the "official" .zip release and place that into SVN, too. At least for compiled languages like Java, the source tree will never look like the release tree anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the **svnmucc** program provided by subversion (included in windows builds since SVN1.5)
This small tool will collect multiple svnactions into a single commit. however you need to create the destination folder before. It is not possible to create a folder and copy content inside in a single transaction: here a sample:

```
svn mkdir -m "creating a tag" http://your.serv.er/svn/repo/tags/release_123
svnmucc cp HEAD http://your.serv.er/svn/repo/trunk/dir1 http://your.serv.er/svn/repo/tags/release_123 \
cp HEAD http://your.serv.er/svn/repo/trunk/file1 http://your.serv.er/svn/repo/tags/release_123 \
cp HEAD http://your.serv.er/svn/repo/trunk/file2 http://your.serv.er/svn/repo/tags/release_123 -m "creating tag Part II"
```

You can also use the perl/python/ruby bindings or svnkit(java) to accomplish this task, but I cannot provide sourcecode for this..

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can.

But why do you need to delete the unit-test directory anyway?
It takes up no extra space in the repository, in fact, it takes up more space if you delete it (because of the extra commit).

If you are worried that a check-out of the tag takes too long / gets too big, you can choose to not check-out the unit-test directory.